# I can't connect an object class file to a uitableview? ios objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, drag-and-drop

Hi I am trying to integrate http://www.scott-sherwood.com/tutorial/ios-5-drag-and-drop-between-uitableviews/ tutorial's function that we can drag and drop objects between two `UITableViews` located in a `UIViewController.`
But In the tutorial it has 2 `tableview` class files(without `xib / ui`) that connects to 2 `tableviews` which located at `SSViewcontroller` as objects.

In the sample source code they provided, I can drag from object to `UITableView` to connect.

But when I try to do with my project I can't connect and `tableview` is not active.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zm9II.jpg)

Any ideas to connect the `tableview` to the object that has a `UITableView` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify outlets in the `UIViewController` subclass that is your file owner. For example, in my case I have these two outlets:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView2;

@end
```

and in Interface Builder it looks like that:

[image]

Comment: It sorted now. Anyway Thanks. The Mistakes I have done was I first connected object with it's property by manually edited the mainviewcontroller.h .        but the later I realized that it should like this. 1. Add Object - Specify the object class first then connect the outlets.